# Shell script running from php code is using /sbin/nologin how to set this to /bin/bash

Tags: linux, shell

I am running a shell script by which we are scheduling a task using at command. But it schedules the at task but its not running the same beacuse its using shell /sbin/nologin when we are calling it from php code. It works fine if we run it from terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the "$PATH" env variable. When you are logged in from terminal the shell has initialized it's search path via .bashrc etc. "cron" or "at" jobs don't do that.

So try to log the environment variables to a file in your 'at' jobs and check if it is set up right.